# C++ Let's Encrypt certificate with websocketpp

Tags: c++, ssl, websocket

i'm using websocketpp to create websockets in C++. Now i would like to run a  websocket server with ssl. I understand that i need a ssl certificate for the server and got one from "Let's Encrypt". 
Now i've got following files:

```
cert1.pem  chain1.pem  fullchain1.pem  privkey1.pem
```

and following code responsible for loading the certificate:

```
ctx->use_certificate_chain_file("server.crt");
ctx->use_private_key_file("server.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
ctx->use_tmp_dh_file("dh512.pem");
```

But i don't know which file to load where and in which format

Comment: @b.sullender: Sorry can't remember